# What happens if I purge unity on a gnome desktop?

Tags: unity, gnome

Currently I am running Ubuntu GNOME switched from Unity 7. While I am in GNOME if I purge or remove unity, does it affect in any way ?

Comment: Did you get your answer?

Comment: @Anwar yes, and I removed Unity and it had no effect on the system. And Gnome is much faster than the Unity desktop. I like it now I would go with Gnome alone in the future distributions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It doesn't affect any way. In fact, many users do that regularly to switch from Unity to Gnome Shell. That's a perfect job to do since you're not willing to use Unity anymore.

Answer (score 1):

No, that won't affect GNOME. I was a Unity user, but I switched to Gnome Shell, and deleted Unity. Nothing happened.